# no module named pyperclip after exe has been created

Tags: python, exe, py2exe, pyinstaller, pyperclip

The script I'm running works great on `.py` and also if i run it as `.exe` from the python file.
but when i export it to one stand alone exe file i get the error in the pic.
i tried already `py2exe + Pyinstaller + "hidden" (option) + DLLs` have been copied to the directory.
the issue seems to be the "Pyperclip module" after the compilation has been made.

I'm working on **WIN 8.1** with **Python 2.7**
let me double explain the `.exe` run after the compilation but when i press the hotkeys **WIN + F2** as i wrote in my "DEF" it crashes with that error.

[image]

Comment: please include your code

Comment: did you install `pyperclip` ????????

Comment: yes of course the code is working! only after it has been transformed to .exe it started to crash

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help, a friend figured it out...

while running the py2exe it couldn't find a module named Pyperclip.

in order to fix it we have copied the pyperclip folder(the one that holds "**init**.py" inside) from the "LIB" to the main folder C\python27\

and then the PY2EXE was able to compile the exe without errors.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you!

This solution worked perfectly for me on a Raspberrypi 3.
I had the same error code and needed to copy

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

to

```
/home/pi
```